# Update Facebook status externally using PHP with username and password of an User

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possibile to update the status of facebook externally using a user's username and password with PHP. without any user interaction(like facebook connect). 
Also without using curl. 
I know there are come facebook mobile clients like snaptu. how do they access inbox, wall and our status just knowing the username and password.?? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Facebook forbids this, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using CURL or other POST requests it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have against cURL, but you can do this with any HTTP client that can handle cookie (or that you can roll cookie support for).

However **you should not even remotely consider doing this**!  Unless it's for a hacky script that will never leave your computer and that you use for your own account.  You should **never** be asking for other peoples' passwords.  Use OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

How can you even think about not using cURL? All the FB API is exposed via HTTP, and if you don't end up using cURL, you will use HTTP anyway, and construct the HTTP request manually and send it via bare sockets.

And that's where cURL could use your job. But it's basically the same.

The apps you're mentioning are screen scraping the FB website and send the HTTP request accordingly - with cURL.